# How do I remove stocks from the stock card settings in Google Now?

Tags: google-now

I have added some stocks to the stock card settings that I want to remove, how do I do that? There is no obvious way, I tried long press & swiping but those gestures do nothing.

Answer (score 7):

**In Android 4.4:**

1. Open Google Now.
2. Press the Options button in upper right corner of the Stock Card.
3. Press the Right Arrow to cycle through options for the card.
4. When asked about "Interested in the stock UNWANTED-STOCK-NAME?", tap "NO".

[image: Stock Card Options]

**In older versions:**

This should do it for you:

1. Open Google Now
2. Press the menu button
3. Press Settings

   [image: Settings]
4. Press Google Now

   [image: Google Now]
5. Scroll down and press Stocks

   [image: Stocks]
6. Press the stock you want to remove

   [image: Press Stock]
7. Press Remove

   [image: Press Remove]